# Android Management API How to Identify Enrolled Device

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I have many devices enrolled, now the problem is that i can't identify the device name on device, when I query EMM I got the list of devices with name of the devices are unique for example: name of device is `enterprises/xxxxx/devices/abc123"`

Now i want to see physically which device is it, how can i do it? there is any way we can display device EMM name on lock screen or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Hardware details such as **brand**, **hardware**, **deviceBasebandVersion**, **manufacturer**, **serialNumber** and **model** in the **hardwareInfo** object of each device details from the list.

Moreover, if you want other details such as **networkInfo** you need to enable **StatusReportingSettings** with **networkInfoEnabled** set to **true** while provisioning. Then it would be much easier for searching with provided information.

See here:

https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#StatusReportingSettings